# for_each usage in C++

Tags: c++, foreach, stl-algorithm, function-object

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class Abstract
{
    //contains a pure virtual function
};

class Mock
{
public:
   Mock();

 ~Mock()
 {
    std::for_each(m_abs_list.begin(), m_abs_list.end(), my_func);    
 } 

 void my_func(Abstract *ele){delete ele;} 

private:
   std::list <Abstract *> m_abs_list;
};
```

Basically, I am trying to call the destructor for each `Abstract` object in the `m_abs_list`. This can be easily achieved by a `for` loop. But I am trying to used `for_each` in this context.

On compilation I get error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In function '_Function std::for_each(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Function) [with _InputIterator = std::_List_iterator<Abstract *>, _Function = void (Mock::*)(Abstract *)]'

/usr/include/c++/4.2/bits/stl_algo.h:159: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in '__f (...)'.
```

How do i get around the compilation error ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't go around it, fix it! ;) You've written `.` instead of `,` in here:

```
for_each(m_abs_list.begin(). m_abs_list.end(), my_func)
```

Also, no semicolon (`;`).

Comment: That's an error in the code he posted yes, but not the cause of his problem.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I thought I was the only one to notice!

Comment: `my_func` is a non-static member function, so the `for_each` still woudn't work!

Comment: also missing std:: in front of for_each.

Comment: @DeadMG, Mooing Duck: You're right and I should learn to read. I've noticed one other thing, though: `Class` uppercase `C`. If the author of the question had posted the actual code, maybe I wouldn't waste everybody's time with spelling corrections.

Comment: @Staven: It is totally not your fault, and I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 4):

Some silly typos, but more importantly, you're trying to pass a member function as if it was a free function. Member functions require special usage- in the general case, you can use boost:bind. But in this case, since it doesn't depend on any instance variables, the easiest thing to do is just make it static.

Oh, and by the way, *use smart pointers*. Seriously. Do not use raw pointers.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any reason for the function to be a member, even.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use my_func like this because it is a member function and every member function is linked to a class and needs a pointer to this class to be used. In standard C++ you'd have to use bind functions (like bind1st) to create a functor that contains a pointer to your object that you can pass to the member function.

Of course, you can also directly makes a functor or use a free function ( or a static function in a class ). If you're using boost, you can also use boost::bind functions which are easier (it is not their only advantage) to write than standard ones. (and I don't mention boost or C++11 lambdas ).

If you don't know what a functor is, it is a class that redefines its operator() function. All STL algorithm are made to use them.

In your case, the easy way is just to create a free function. Of course, you should also use if you can smart pointers like boost::shared_ptr, you will gain considerable advantages in memory management.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a smart pointer (other than auto_ptr) for memory management.

That way, when your member list is destroyed, it will release any heap-allocated memory along with it.

However, if you don't want to do that and unless you are restricted to using a compiler that doesn't support lambdas...

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

class Abstract
{
    //contains a pure virtual function
};

class Mock
{
public:
   Mock();

 ~Mock()
 {
    std::for_each(m_abs_list.begin(), m_abs_list.end(), [](Abstract *ele)
    { delete ele; });
 } 

private:
   std::list <Abstract *> m_abs_list;
};
```

Comment: Wow, this is utterly terrible. You're fixing the tiny little error and ignoring the massive, crippling memory management sinkhole.

Comment: You must have missed my very first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this is not the "right" way to do this. But, here is what you are trying to do...

```
std::for_each(m_abs_list.begin(), m_abs_list.end(),
              std::bind1st(std::mem_fun<void, Mock, Abstract*>(&Mock::my_func), this);
```

I am away from my development system, so there may be some syntax errors.